# Discharging Assumptions and Conditional Introduction (Chiswell and Hodges)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

I'm currently working through the Chiswell and Hodges *Mathematical Logic* and found myself a little puzzled by a particular natural deduction issue for ($\to$I). The exercise I'm a little stuck on wants me to write out the sequent that is proved by the derivation:

[Derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZtfQ.png)

So it certainly seems to me true that $\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \phi))$, but I'm having a hard time convincing myself that this is what the derivation above is proving. The natural deduction rule for conditional introduction presented in the book is:

[ND Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkJlL.png)

This rule allows you to discharge an assumption $\phi$ after a derivation to $\psi$ and conclude $(\phi\to\psi)$, but I'm not seeing how the rule can allow you to reach a statement where the assumption is in the consequent. It feels like there ought to be a $\psi$ lurking around somewhere in order to make this work according to the rule.

So here's my question: is the key here that ($\to$I) *allows* you to discharge the assumption of the antecedent when you write down the conditional but doesn't *require* it? So if I treat the appearance of $\phi$ as like the $\psi$ in the rule pictured, the rule tells me: 'if you had a $\psi$ above you could discharge it in order to write down the conditional, but it's not necessary'?

Does this mean, for instance, that before the second step in the derivation pictured is taken, we would have something like this:

[Test Derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwxD4.png)

which would be a derivation that shows that $\phi \vdash (\psi\to\phi)$?

If any of the above rambling makes sense, then I think it follows that the derivation does indeed prove that $\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \phi))$. Apologies for any lack of clarity -- I'm accustomed to other natural deduction systems and am encountering this one for the first time.

Comment: See [van Dalen, page 34](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf) : "Furthermore one may apply (→I) if there is no hypothesis available for cancellation; e.g. $\dfrac {ϕ} {ψ→ϕ}$ is a correct derivation, using just (→I)."

Comment: Another approach is to "fix" H&C's system adding [see page 8] this obvious SEQUENT RULE (Weakening Rule) : if $(\Gamma \vdash \phi)$ is correct, then $(\Gamma \cup \{ \psi \} \vdash \phi)$ is correct, for every $\psi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right ... something is fishy here.

Now, first of all, the statement $\psi \to \phi$ is a logical consequence of $\phi$ ... and so it would be perfectly ok to define an inference rule of the form:

\begin{array}{cc}
\phi\\
\hline
\psi \to \phi & \to I\\
\end{array}

... which is of course your Test Derivation.

*BUT* ... this does not seem to be how this book defines the $\to \ I$ rule!
 Unless I am missing something, they define it as you indicate: you *have* to have the antecedent at the top, and then you discharge it with this rule.

> It feels like there ought to be a $\psi$ lurking around somewhere in order to make this work according to the rule.

Exactly! Like you, I don't see how the first Derivation is compatible with the rules as defined in their book.

I think a proper derivation would be:

\begin{array}{cc}
\require{cancel} \cancel{\psi}_1 \quad \cancel{\phi}_2\\
\hline
\psi \to \phi & \to I_1\\
\hline
\phi \to (\psi \to \phi) & \to I_2
\end{array}

... although it doesn't seem you can have these side-by-side statements above a $\to I$ application ...

so maybe:

\begin{array}{cc}
\require{cancel} \cancel{\phi}_2\\
\require{cancel} \cancel{\psi}_1\\ 
\hline
\psi \to \phi & \to I_1\\
\hline
\phi \to (\psi \to \phi) & \to I_2
\end{array}

.. but it seems the $\phi$ should be below the $\psi$ in order to do the first $\to I$?

OK, so maybe:

\begin{array}{cc}
\require{cancel} \cancel{\psi}_1\\ 
\require{cancel} \cancel{\phi}_2\\
\hline
\psi \to \phi & \to I_1\\
\hline
\phi \to (\psi \to \phi) & \to I_2
\end{array}

I *think* that one is OK. In the Appendix, they do say that:

\begin{array}{c}
\phi
\end{array}

is a derivation, and so with their $\to I$ rule, that seems to work.  If not, we'd have to somehow first *derive* $\phi$.

So, if it had a 'Reiteration' rule:

\begin{array}{cc}
\require{cancel} \cancel{\psi}_1\\ 
\hline
\require{cancel} \cancel{\phi}_2\\
\hline
\phi \quad Reit\\
\hline
\psi \to \phi & \to I_1\\
\hline
\phi \to (\psi \to \phi) & \to I_2
\end{array}

But the system does not seem to have a Reiteration rule, in which case we'd be forced to do something like:

\begin{array}{cc}
\require{cancel} \cancel{\psi}_1 \quad \cancel{\phi}_2\\
\hline
\psi \land \phi \quad \land I\\
\hline
\phi \quad \land E\\
\hline
\psi \to \phi & \to I_1\\
\hline
\phi \to (\psi \to \phi) & \to I_2
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks! Nice to feel a little less insane at least.

Interestingly in a subsequent exercise they ask you to prove $\vdash (\phi \to (\psi \to \psi))$. The only way I can see to do this at present runs near the same fishy territory. You'd need to produce $(\psi \to \psi)$ first, which is fine, and then without strictly speaking discharging anything conclude $(\phi \to (\psi \to \psi))$, citing ($\to$I). But this is, for the same reasons, puzzling.

Comment: Yeah, I think that would have to be: \begin{array}{cc}
\require{cancel} \cancel{\psi}_1 \quad \cancel{\phi}_2\\
\hline
\psi \to \psi & \to I_1\\
\hline
\phi \to (\psi \to \psi) & \to I_2
\end{array}

Comment: So this is interesting. I thought about this, but I've not yet in the textbook seen any rules or comments that allow you to stack or branch assumptions like that without the use of rules like ($\wedge$I) or something like that, and none of the examples work that way. That's not to say that this doesn't make intuitive sense (it just seems to me like writing out all the premises in a Fitch-style natural deduction).

Comment: I tried a few other formats in my Answer ....

Comment: Oh yes thank you! In fact that last one in the absence of a reiteration rule looks to me the most compatible with the approach and rules in Chiswell and Hodges. It's still puzzling that they provide the derivation that they do, but this has cleared a lot up for me.

Comment: @tspmckenna You're welcome!  Glad I could help.  And yeah .. not a fan of this notation myself ... (let alone the typesetting ...)

Answer (score 0):

> So here's my question: is the key here that (→I) allows you to discharge the assumption of the antecedent when you write down the conditional but doesn't require it?

Yes, that's right. The book spells this out, "The rule is still correctly applied if we do not discharge all of [the occurrences of the assumption]; in fact the rule is correctly applied even if φ is not an assumption of D at all, so that there is nothing to discharge."